# In Selenium using Python facing error unable to locate element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()

# Navigate to the application home page
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

# get the search textbox
search_field = driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
search_field.clear()

# enter search keyword and submit
search_field.send_keys("Selenium WebDriver Interview questions")
search_field.submit()

# get the list of elements which are displayed after the search
# currently on result page using find_elements_by_class_name method
lists= driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_Rm")

# get the number of elements found
print ("Found " + str(len(lists)) + " searches:")

# iterate through each element and print the text that is
# name of the search

i=0
for listitem in lists:
   print (listitem.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
   i=i+1
   if(i>10):
      break

# close the browser window
driver.quit()
```

Error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:/Users/HP/Documents/selenium1.py", line 13, in <module>
    search_field = driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="lst-ib"]
```

Comment: Considering that the google.com source code does not include an element with id="lst-ib", and the search input field does not have an id attribute, it's not surprising that you're getting the error Unable to locate element. I recommend starting by right-clicking the element you're targeting, then choosing Inspect Element. That will highlight the element code in the developer tools. You'll find that the search field's most useful attribute is name="q"

Comment: Kate's comment is correct. Additionally, Google's DOM is not robot friendly. If you are doing this as an exercise, I would suggest going to DuckDuckGo.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to introduce [Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) and use correct locators.

For example:

1. Change this line:

   ```
   search_field = driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
   ```

   to this one:

   ```
   search_field = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='q']")))
   ```
2. Similarly:

   remove this line:

   ```
   lists= driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_Rm")
   ```

   and use the following instead:

   ```
   wait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("r")) > 0)
   lists = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("r")
   ```

You will need the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

More information:

- [Selenium Python Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)
- [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)